# For loop get iteration number using only i and j

Tags: for-loop

I ran through questions with similar titles but could not find them anywhere. Suppose I have a for loop (regardless of the programming language)

```
for (i=0; i < n; i++)
    for (j=0; j < m; j++)
        k = ...
        print("k is: " + k)
```

I now want to calculate `k` based ONLY on `i` and `j` where `k` is the iteration count. So for example when `n=2` and `m=2` than we should get

```
k is 0
k is 1
k is 2
k is 3
```

Is this possible only using `i` and `j` or do I need to introduce another variable which gets incremented each time? This question is more theoretical as one can always simply solve an actual problem by using a counter. Note: starting at one in the print is also good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it without knowing either m or n

```
k = i * m + j
```

Or

```
k = i + j * n
```

And to start by 1:

```
k = i * m + j + 1
```

or

```
k = i + j * n + 1
```

Comment: `m` and `n` are indeed required for it. Your formula was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I also added the other cases.